# streaming wav from objective C to nodejs

Tags: objective-c, node.js

Trying to stream audio from my iOS app to a nodejs server, .wav file would never open.

I am not sure what am I missing, do I need to add some metadata to the .wav file so an audio player can open it?

I have been searching for hours, not sure where my problem is, any pointers would help.

```
var util = require('util'),
http = require('http'),
httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
fs = require('fs');
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('audio.wav');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    wstream.write(chunk);
  });
  req.on('end', function () {
    wstream.end();
    console.log("file saved");
    res.writeHead(200);res.write("OK");res.end();
    });
}).listen(9000);
```

Objective C:

```
-(BOOL)startRequestWithContext:(NSMutableDictionary *)context {
    requestEnding = NO;
    NSString* token = [[WITState sharedInstance] accessToken];

    // CF wiring
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    readStream = NULL;
    writeStream = NULL;
    CFStreamCreateBoundPair(NULL, &readStream, &writeStream, 65536);

    // convert to NSStream and set as property
    inStream = CFBridgingRelease(readStream);
    outStream = CFBridgingRelease(writeStream);

    [outStream setDelegate:self];
    [outStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outStream open];

    NSString* urlString;

    urlString = kWitSpeechURL;

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [req setTimeoutInterval:15.0];
    [req setHTTPBodyStream:inStream];
    [req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [req setValue:@"wit/ios" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [req setValue:@"chunked" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Transfer-encoding"];
    [req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    // send HTTP request
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
      NSError *serializationError;
      NSDictionary *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&serializationError];
      [self.delegate gotResponse:object error:nil];
    }];

return YES;
}


  -(void)sendChunk:(NSData*)chunk {

      debug(@"Adding operation %u bytes", (unsigned int)[chunk length]);
      [q addOperationWithBlock:^{
          if (outStream) {
              [q setSuspended:YES];

              debug(@"Uploading %u bytes", (unsigned int)[chunk length]);
              [outStream write:[chunk bytes] maxLength:[chunk length]];
          }

          NSUInteger cnt = q.operationCount;
          debug(@"Operation count: %d", cnt);
          if (requestEnding && cnt <= 1) {
              [self cleanUp];
          }
      }];
  }


-(void)recorderGotChunk:(NSData*)chunk {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(self.isUploading) {
        [self.uploader sendChunk:chunk];
    } else {
        //not uploading, so save the chunk to the buffer and remove old chunk
        if ([self.dataBuffer count] >= self.buffersToSave){
            //if we have enough entries, remove the oldest one
            [self.dataBuffer removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
        //enqueue the new data
        [self.dataBuffer addObject:chunk];
    }
        [self.delegate recordingSessionRecorderGotChunk:chunk];
    });
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the iOS side as well. Note that in your code above, you create a single write stream, then write to it and close it. You probably want to open the file (a different one) when you receive a new request instead.

Comment: @jcaron yes I understand that, I just want to get the simplest example working, then I would work on managing multiple requests

Comment: Still need the iOS side, though...

Comment: The code you posted doesn't show you sending anything. You create a bound pair of streams, but don't do anything with it other that connect it to the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using the NSOperationQueue looks pretty suspicious to me - you're suspending the queue, but never un-suspending it, examining the number of operations in the queue in order to decide when to clean up, etc.

The way I would expect this to work is that you create the queue, add the various sendChunk: operations, then add a close/cleanup operation at the end. Then the queue executes the operations in order. If there's an error, you can call cancelAllOperations on the queue...

Comment: a clean up function is being called after the recording session is finished, the NSOperationQueue gets unsuspended at the end.